# Sass --watch in particular order

Tags: compiler-construction, sass, watch

In textmate, my .scss files are in alphabetical order. I compile them into .css files.

```
sass --watch css/sass:css/compiled
```

I'm getting errors though because I need my variables, mixins and resets to be compiled first, followed by the rest of the files.

How can I set the order in which the files get compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have file structure like this:

```
css/sass/main.scss
css/sass/mixins.scss
css/sass/print.scss
css/sass/reset.scss
css/sass/variables.scss
```

Those files are called **partials**. Another thing you need to do is add **`_`** (underscore) before each filename, like this:

```
css/sass/_main.scss
css/sass/_mixins.scss
css/sass/_print.scss
css/sass/_reset.scss
css/sass/_variables.scss
```

This will tell Sass not to compile those files to separate .css files.

Now you want to compile them into single file. Create new file, `style.scss` (without underscore) here:

```
css/sass/style.scss
```

Open it and put your partial files in desired order there:

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "reset";
@import "main";
@import "print";
```

Note that underscore at the beggining of file don't have to be in the definition, Sass will handle it for you.

Now you can run

```
sass --watch css/sass:css/compiled
```

and Sass will compile content of all partial files into one single file located in

```
css/compiled/style.css
```